# Error type I for $X_i \sim Exp(\theta)$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, chi-squared-test, gamma-distribution

Let $ X_i$ be i.i.d $Exp(\theta)$ for i=1,...,4.We want to test $H_0: \theta =6$ versus $ H_1: \theta = 2$. Consider the following test:

$$\text{Test: Rejects H_o} \iff \frac{X_1 + X_2}{2}>4.5$$

Evaluate the probability of error type I

**My attempt:**

For the iid exponential we have that

$$Y=X_1+X_2 \sim Gamma(2,\theta)$$

So,

$$\alpha=P(\text{Error type I})=P(Y > 9|H_0) = P(Y>9|\theta=6)$$

Under $ H_0,$

$$Y \sim Gamma(2,6)$$

Then,

$$12Y \sim Gamma(\frac{4}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) = \chi^2(4)$$
$$\Rightarrow \alpha=P(12Y>108|H_0)$$

Is that correct? I couldnt find a good table that gives this value, so I thought there could be somehing wrong. If one could indicate a reliable table for chi-squared, I would be glad!

Thanks!

**@Edit**:

[This](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=yAkvVJjjD4TgsATzhoL4CA&url=http://stat.psu.edu/~mga/401/tables/Chi-square-table.pdf&cd=6&ved=0CDIQFjAF&usg=AFQjCNFuwKleTzB8plcVC0eecgCxbBlXxQ&sig2=y7qGreQ3SCBMn5ElGhPvHg) table is great, but I think that 108 is tpo high (with makes me to have doubts about my solution). If it is correct, it follows that $\alpha$ is very close to 0.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: there are two common [parameterizations for the Gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) (see the two columns of summary on the right) - the shape-rate form (which you seem to be using) and the shape-scale form. You might consider whether it's possible that the shape-scale form was intended here. But in any case, exact probabilities for a Gamma with shape parameter 2 can be found via integration by parts.